# Patent Application WO 2013155313 A2

Tags: wo2013155313a2

If there is a company in the market that has been using numerous of the methods in matching up LKQ products and a coordinating database how does that effect this potential patent?  If the person seeking the patent did not disclose the known company that has been doing this since 1993 what effect would that have on the patent if issued? Many of the claims of the patent are very broad and seem like they could cause infringement issues for many businesses.  Do they seem reasonable to be allowed by the patent office?

Answer (score 1):

The WO number referenced in the tag is an international PCT application. There is also a corresponding U.S. application US20140025433. It has not been examined yet but the applicant has filed an Information Disclosure Statement listing things they know that might be relevant.

[image]

Applicants need to disclose *only what they know about* so omission of some possible prior art is not held against the applicant unless it can be shown that they knew about it, knew it was relevant and purposely didn't disclose it. Of course the prior art, when unearthed, itself can be used against the application or issued patent.